# Cross Domain SPServices

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, spservices

I have two SharePoint web apps `site1.spnet.local` and `site2.spnet.local`. Im looking to make some cross domain spservices requests using a reverse proxy. The reverse proxy appears to be transforming `site1.spnet.local/api` to `site2.spnet.local` but im constantly getting **401 responses**. We have windows authentication using Kerberos. Is the concept of what i am trying to do possible?